# Вызвать событие "contextmenu" на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Задача: вызвать из тела функции событие contextmenu на конкретном DOM-елементе.

То есть у меня есть елемент

```
const $a = document.getElementById("MenuView_clustersAnchor")
```

на нем уже весит обработчик события .oncontextmenu и логика работает.

Необходимо сделать райт клик (вызов contextmenu) на этом элементе из скрипта.
Например обычный .click() вызывается нормально.
При .contextmenu() ничего не происходит.

Comment: А что мешает вызвать функцию-обработчик напрямую без всяких событий?

Comment: @andreymal, довольно часто что-нибудь мешает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо создать [свой Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) и вызвать его у элемента

```js
const eventContextMenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu');
btn.dispatchEvent(eventContextMenu);
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

let counter = 0;

btn.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  output.innerHTML = `${e.type} сработал ${counter} раз`; 
});

const eventContextMenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu');
btn.dispatchEvent(eventContextMenu);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: border-color, color, background-color;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Пример, что это реально работает(`contextmenu` событие для кнопки вызывается раз в 0.5 секунды):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

let counter = 0;

btn.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  output.innerHTML = `${e.type} сработал ${counter} раз`; 
});

setInterval(() => {
  const eventContextMenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu');
  btn.dispatchEvent(eventContextMenu);
}, 500);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: border-color, color, background-color;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Через старую запись on(событие):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

let counter = 0;

btn.oncontextmenu = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  output.innerHTML = `${e.type} сработал ${counter} раз`; 
};

const eventContextMenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu');
btn.dispatchEvent(eventContextMenu);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: border-color, color, background-color;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Впринципе, можно сделать и через вызов contextmenu(), написать его самому в `prototype` для [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element):

```js
Element.prototype.contextmenu = function() {
  const eventContextMenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu');
  this.dispatchEvent(eventContextMenu);
};

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

let counter = 0;

btn.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  output.innerHTML = `${e.type} сработал ${counter} раз`; 
});

btn.contextmenu();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: border-color, color, background-color;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Михаил, спасибо. Информация полезная, но не решает до конца мою проблему.

У меня задача такая:
есть большой легаси код, в нем уже есть логика события oncontextmenu. в это меню парсится html  с сервера. Моя задача написать макрос, который вызывает это уже существующее событие, чтобы нужный html попал в сайт.
Так как бэкенд там генерируется с какого-то старого Perl + JAVA кода, у меня не получается отловить это событие.
То есть мне нужно вызвать не свое кастомное событие contextmenu, а именно уже существующее в проекте.
JS предусмотрел вызов  .click()
А мне нужно так для .contextmenu()

Comment: @flyonk я вызвал это событие, смотрите в код, стоит слушатель события на событие `contextmenu`. Я использую добавление слушателя событие не через on(событие), старую запись, а через addEventListener. У вас этот код будет также работать через oncontextmenu

Comment: @flyonk https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events почитайте

Comment: @mihinov протестировал Ваш код в другом проекте, действительно все работает корректно. Как выяснилось у меня мое созданное событие contextmenu перехватывает фреймворк webadmin, который в корне этого легаси-кода живёт. 
Нашел в итоге решение в документации фреймворка.

Comment: @flyonk если ответ вам помог, можете отметить его галочкой(слева от голосов), это значит, что вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос